# Avoid clipping of axis numbering in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

One of the x-axis numbering (2500) is being clipped by gnuplot as in the attached image (image 1). How to avoid this? Also, how to increase the white space so as to position the Ylabel towards the negative x-axis, to avoid overlapping Ylabel and y-axis numbering (Please refer image 2).

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult a basic gnuplot tutorial and check the manual. I know, as a gnuplot beginner it might be confusing and you don't know where to start and search, but to me, these seem to be a bit *too* basic questions for StackOverflow. A little search certainly would have helped.
In gnuplot console, check `help margins` and `help ylabel` or `help xlabel`.

Set the right margin a bit larger than the automatic value, for example:

```
set rmargin screen 0.9
```

Give the ylabel some extra offset, for example:

```
set ylabel offset -1,0
```

And maybe you have to adjust the left margin as well:

```
set lmargin screen 0.1
```